# Minimum subset of rules

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have these rules and I need to find the minimum subset $K \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that:
 1. $2 \in K$
 2. $n^2 \in K \rightarrow n \in K$
 3. $ n \in K \rightarrow (n+5)^2 \in K$
The question is to find a rule of what is in the set and what is not in the set
I tried looping like this: $2,7^2 , 7 , 12^2 , 12, ... $
But couldn't find any law or pattern... any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Keep going, you will see it

Comment: What are the restrictions on how you can express this set? Presumably you're after something in set-builder notation, but can you use union/intersection/etc.?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine everything, modulu, union etc.. :-)